# How do I stop a "fixed" element using following code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

For my current project I want to make a sort of fixed element in my DOM.
I am not using `position: fixed` because the element will lose its existence within the DOM and thus its original position (which in my opinion only makes things look worse). I made the element behave like a fixed element by just adding/removing `margin-top: somevalue` to the scrollable element, everytime when the user scrolls and the code I use was made possible  within the JavaScript. Using this method also adds a nice looking animation to this whole "interaction".

The problem I am experiencing is that when the (browser) window has such a small height, that the element will reach for the footer, it will expand the container, body or whatever parent is on it. How do I prevent this from happening?

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88eu0mbm/1/) per example of this issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var topPadding = 10;
  //Set the scrollable offset before starting the scroll
  var scrollableTopOffset = $(".scrollable").offset().top;

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    /* When scrolling, determine wether the browser window still contains
  scrollable: */
    if (scrollableTopOffset < $(window).scrollTop()) {
      //Code when scrollable is within the browser window...
      //$(".shopping-cart").addClass("scrollable-fixed");
      $(".scrollable").stop().animate({
        marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - scrollableTopOffset + topPadding
      });
    } else {
      //Code when scrollable is not within the browser window...
      //$(".shopping-cart").removeClass("scrollable-fixed");
      $(".scrollable").stop().animate({
        marginTop: 0
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.some-content-block {
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
.scrollable {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: cyan;
}
footer {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container" style="background-color: blue;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="some-content-block">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="some-content-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="some-content-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="some-content-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="some-content-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="some-content-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="some-content-block">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="some-content-block">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <div class="scrollable">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

**Edit:** Here is my fiddle updated with the answer of SamGhatak: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88eu0mbm/3/)

Comment: And then you'll see tons of results using `position` property. Read my question first please. All I need is to stop adding margin once I reach the footer element and I want to know what piece of javascript code can determine that the user reached the footer and does stop adding margin then.

Comment: from the fiddle,it looks ok...which part u want to correct?

Comment: @SamGhatak Make the height of the window you're viewing the fiddle in smaller, then scroll all the way down the footer and keep scrolling untill you notice what happens.

Comment: ok, u dont want to push the footer down?

Comment: @SamGhatak Exactly. It's where I want to stop adding margin.

Comment: $(".container").css("height") gives you the height of your container, where scrollable floats arround. so all you have to do is, stop the animation, if margin:top + scrollable.height > container.height ...

Comment: @errand Thanks I was looking for something in this direction, I will see if I can make something with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a solution here:

https://jsfiddle.net/rv4mg8uq/2/

Added this code there:

```
if(($('footer').offset().top -scrollableTopOffset +topPadding)<$(window).scrollTop()){
        //do nothing
}
```

Comment: Yes I tried to see for myself what you did with the code you made and it looks like it works very well. I will apply this to my code to see if all works fine. Thanks for this answer.